# How should I read a file line-by-line in Python?

Tags: python

In pre-historic times (Python 1.4) we did:

```
fp = open('filename.txt')
while 1:
    line = fp.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line)
```

after Python 2.1, we did:

```
for line in open('filename.txt').xreadlines():
    print(line)
```

before we got the convenient iterator protocol in Python 2.3, and could do:

```
for line in open('filename.txt'):
    print(line)
```

I've seen some examples using the more verbose:

```
with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

Is this the preferred method going forward?

[edit] I get that the with statement ensures closing of the file. Why isn't that included in the iterator protocol for file objects?

Comment: imho, the last suggestion is no more verbose than the one before. It just does more work (ensures the file gets closed when you're done).

Comment: @azhrei it's one line more, so objectively it is more verbose.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I'm just saying comparing apples with apples, the second last suggestion in your post needs exception handling code as well to match what the last option does. So in practice it's more verbose. I guess it depends on context which of the last two options is best, really.

Comment: I found this to be a clearly better version of the question than the more popular canonicals. The question doesn't include a strange example (trying to create a cartesian product of lines in the file, which comes with several of its own problems), and has answers that are both properly scoped and give a solid explanation. It also happens to show working code up front, which makes it easier to use for people who get here from a search engine.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The added version ranges (inside the code samples) don't add anything of use over just when the feature was introduced. It is assumed that if something is introduced in a version it is the intended way forwards.  The title says that this question is about reading line-by-line and not reading binary files (which is very different). If you want to edit the last example to use the print-function rather than the print-statement that would seem appropriate - having two versions that only differ in whether there are parens around print doesn't seem clarifying.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

There is exactly one reason why the following is preferred:

```
with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

We are all spoiled by CPython's relatively deterministic reference-counting scheme for garbage collection.  Other, hypothetical implementations of Python will not necessarily close the file "quickly enough" without the `with` block if they use some other scheme to reclaim memory.

In such an implementation, you might get a "too many files open" error from the OS if your code opens files faster than the garbage collector calls finalizers on orphaned file handles.  The usual workaround is to trigger the GC immediately, but this is a nasty hack and it has to be done by **every** function that could encounter the error, including those in libraries.  What a nightmare.

Or you could just use the `with` block.

### Bonus Question

(Stop reading now if are only interested in the objective aspects of the question.)

> Why isn't that included in the iterator protocol for file objects?

This is a subjective question about API design, so I have a subjective answer in two parts.

On a gut level, this feels wrong, because it makes iterator protocol do two separate things—iterate over lines *and* close the file handle—and it's often a bad idea to make a simple-looking function do two actions.  In this case, it feels especially bad because iterators relate in a quasi-functional, value-based way to the contents of a file, but managing file handles is a completely separate task.  Squashing both, invisibly, into one action, is surprising to humans who read the code and makes it more difficult to reason about program behavior.

Other languages have essentially come to the same conclusion.  Haskell briefly flirted with so-called "lazy IO" which allows you to iterate over a file and have it automatically closed when you get to the end of the stream, but it's almost universally discouraged to use lazy IO in Haskell these days, and Haskell users have mostly moved to more explicit resource management like Conduit which behaves more like the `with` block in Python.

On a technical level, there are some things you may want to do with a file handle in Python which would not work as well if iteration closed the file handle.  For example, suppose I need to iterate over the file twice:

```
with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        ...
    fp.seek(0)
    for line in fp:
        ...
```

While this is a less common use case, consider the fact that I might have just added the three lines of code at the bottom to an existing code base which originally had the top three lines.  If iteration closed the file, I wouldn't be able to do that.  So keeping iteration and resource management separate makes it easier to compose chunks of code into a larger, working Python program.

Composability is one of the most important usability features of a language or API.

Comment: even with alternate implementation, the with handler is only going to cause you problems for programs that opens hundreds of files in a very quick successions. Most programs can get by with the dangling file reference with no issue. Unless you disable it, eventually the GC will kick in sometime and clear up the file handle. `with` does give you the peace of mind though, so it's still a best practice.

Comment: @LieRyan: Dangling references are an unrelated concept.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: perhaps "dangling file reference" were not the right words, I really meant file handles that were no longer accessible but not closed yet. In any case, the GC will close the file handle when it collects the file object, therefore as long as you don't have extra references to the file object and you don't disable GC and you're not opening many files in quick succession, you're unlikely to get "too many files open" due to not closing the file.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean by "if your code opens files faster than the garbage collector calls finalizers on orphaned file handles".

Comment: The bigger reason to use with is that if you don't close the file, it won't necessarily get written immediately.

Answer (score 25):

Yes,

```
with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

is the way to go.

It is not more verbose. It is more safe.

Answer (score 5):

if you're turned off by the extra line, you can use a wrapper function like so:

```
def with_iter(iterable):
    with iterable as iter:
        for item in iter:
            yield item

for line in with_iter(open('...')):
    ...
```

in Python 3.3, the `yield from` statement would make this even shorter:

```
def with_iter(iterable):
    with iterable as iter:
        yield from iter
```

Comment: call the function xreadlines.. and put it in a file named xreadlines.py and we're back to Python 2.1 syntax :-)

Comment: @thebjorn: perhaps, but the Python 2.1 example you cited were not safe from unclosed file handler in alternate implementations. A Python 2.1 file reading that is safe from unclosed file handler would take at least 5 lines.