# Mock for line in open(file):

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am wanting to unittest a component of my application. The code looks a little like below.

```
def read_content_generator(myfile):
    for line in open(myfile):
        # do some string manipulation.
        yield result
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot mock the `open()` functionality within a `for` loop.

What I am aiming for is a `unittest` like this: (I know this code is not right but its just an example of what I am trying to do):

```
def test_openiteration(self):
    with mock.patch('open') as my_openmock:
        my_openmock.return_value = ['1','2','3']
        response = myfunction()
        self.assertEquals([1,2,3], response)
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what the goal is here. Can you clarify?

Comment: @veedrac Apologies I have now reworded

Answer (score 10):

You can mock `open()` to return StringIO object.

**mymodule.py:**

```
def read_content_generator(myfile):
    with open(myfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield '<{}>'.format(line)
```

Note that I've used [with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11555509/3227133) there.

**test_mymodule.py:**

```
import io
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

import mymodule


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_gen(self):
        fake_file = io.StringIO('foo\nbar\n')
        with mock.patch('mymodule.open', return_value=fake_file, create=True):
            result = list(mymodule.read_content_generator('filename'))
        self.assertEqual(result, ['<foo\n>' , '<bar\n>'])
```

Works for python3.4.

At first I tried to use `mock.mock_open(read_data='1\n2\n3\n')` but iteration support seems to be broken.

Comment: Using python 2.7.13, I had to use `StringIO.StringIO` instead of `io.StringIO`

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy options available:

- Change `read_content_generator` to take a file, not a file name, and mock that with an `io.StringIO`.
- Make a temporary file. There are good modules for this.

Comment: tempfile works. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile-examples It's also possible that your function works with a StringIO object.