# python unittest dependencies with file IO

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have two functions

```
def complex_func():
   # generate result.csv
  
def post_process_func(csv_fname):
    # do something with result.csv
```

and I want to make a unittest for each function

```
def test_complex_func():
   complex_func()
   assert result.csv exists
   assert contents of result.csv is correct
```

However, to test `post_process_func` I need a result.csv so I need to call `complex_func()` and it causes dependency issue between two unittests.

I searched and found `mock` or `patch` but those are useful to override the return value of function or object, not the file IO.

What's the best way to separate these two unittests in python way?

Comment: Depending on the contents of the file, you could use `BytesIO` to mock the contents of a file. I think reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24325868/8868327) answer might help you

Comment: Also if you have a working file that you could use as a fixture, just store it in your project with your tests and use it, not to depend on the function producing the file