# Find/replace in large datasets with Python

Tags: python

I have a 3GB file `a.txt` of the form:

```
a 20
g 33
e 312
....
```

And a `b.txt` file which is a map to the alphabet in `a.txt`:

```
e elephant
a apple
g glue
....
```

I'd like to merge these two files to create `c.txt` like:

```
apple 20
glue 33
elephant 312
...
```

I have tried to write a simple for loop to do that but failed. When I run the python file, it runs 2 seconds and stop.

Comment: What exactly makes it impossible to write a simple `for` loop? Just don't load the entire file into memory. Anyways, this has been done a million times, let me look for a duplicate.

Comment: @N.Wouda how can I do that?

Comment: @N.Wouda Thank you so much.

Comment: I've flagged too much today, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555468/how-should-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python) is pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: @N.Wouda I used this all the time but it is quite slow when the dataset is bigger than normal

Comment: I am curious how "a" could be so big, there are only 26 letters in the alphabet, What is missing here

Comment: Well, you are reading lots of data from the filesystem, so you really cannot expect great performance (disk IO is just slow).

Comment: @PyNEwbie the first column of `a.txt` probably does not contain unique values (so there will be many entries of `a`, `g` etc.). It's just a record.

Comment: So then what is the output supposed to be, this is easy if there are only 26 keys, it is actually very trivial.  We could process one set of keys at a time open a, consume only the lines that have a-g,, open b consume only lines that have a-g, etc.  but then the output is uncertain, I am confused, if they are not in order and a is a key multiple times how do I know I have 20 apples?

Comment: @PyNEwbie open `b.txt`, build the mapping required for `a.txt` as a dictionary, then process `a.txt` line-by-line and write the mapped values to `c.txt`. Want to earn some simple rep and put this into an answer? I cannot be bothered, as this really should be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @PyNEwbie Actually, that is not exactly the situation is. I simplify the case for convenience. There are unique strings of the items in a.txt and another set of unique strings in b.txt.

Comment: I think there is still some confusion about what the op wants.  so in a we have a_20, but we also have a_n, if the keys are not ordered the same across a & b, what determines the assignment, it it first to first, if so it is still trivial.  I think this question needs some more detail

Comment: so the question is are the "keys' unique - is there only one value for "zsd" in a and one for zsd in b?

Comment: @PyNEwbie Ignore the fact that there are just 26 alphabets. The key and value are one-to-one and they are determined in the b.txt

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with dictionaries like so

```
mapping = {}
with open('b.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    key, value = line.split()
    mapping[key] = value
with open('a.txt') as i:
  with open('c.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in i:
      key, value = line.split()
      if key in mapping:
        print(value, mapping[key], file=o)
```

So what if `a.txt` is 3GB?  On a modern desktop computer this will still run very quickly

Comment: Are you sure you're not mistaking the two files? Shouldn't `a` and `b` be opened the other way around?

Comment: @N.Wouda ok, i did have them mixed up.  Good catch!

Comment: @randomusername I tried in ipython and it even stop to work

Answer (score 0):

well to strictly answer your question, this will read in a.txt, line by line, scan b for a match, write it out, close b, read the next line in a.txt, open b again etc.  This should only read one line in a at a time.  I am inferring that there is a one-to-one non-ordered match.

```
def process(a,b,outpath):
    outref = open(outpath,'w')
    with open(a,'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            key,value = line.split()
            with open(b,'r') as fh_b:
                for b_line in fh_b:
                    bkey, bvalue = b_line.split()
                    if bkey == key:
                        outref.write(bvalue.strip() + ' ' + value.strip() + '\n')
                        continue
    outref.close()
    return
```