# Read data from file without blocking the system

Tags: python, file, nonblocking, read-data

I am new in Python, and I hope that someone can help me.
I have the main loop. IN this loop I want to use data from a file. The main problem, that I need to do this without blocking all the system in between.

Example:

```
f=open("./filename.txt", "r")

while True:

    a=f.readline()
    print("Data: %s" %(a))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output for example

```
Data: Hello
Data: Hello
Data: Hello
...
Until new data
```

Is it possible? I will be so appreciated for this. Any examples and help, please.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Reading from a file doesn't block the system.

Comment: You need to break out of the loop when you get to the end of the file.

Comment: Blocking the system or blocking the main thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I read a file line-by-line in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555468/how-should-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: I mean, If the file will be empty. I do not need to break. I need to read the file all the time.

Comment: blocking the main thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tail a log file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python)