# Different value from .txt for every loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops

I have to change the `res` variable value in the next code for every loop it does.

```
txt = open(os.path.expanduser('~FOLDER\\numbers.txt'), 'r')
res = txt.read().splitlines()

u = [something]    
for item in u:
    var['Number : ' + res[0]]
```

`txt` variable contains a text file. In this text file there some lines of numbers in this format:

```
123
1234
125342
562546
```

I have to take a variable for each loop the script does and assign to `res`. At the moment, with `res[0]` it only iterate the same number (ex: 123) on every loop. How can I solve the problem ?
It should be 0 at first, 1 at second ad so on...

Comment: you set `u` to `[]` and then iterate over it. this will not work. i think you made a copy&paste error here.

Comment: yes, you're right. In full code "u" is not empty...edit now

Comment: you assign u with an empty array and then iterate over it (which is empty)

Comment: What is the point of iterating `item in u` if within the `for` you never use `item`?

Comment: @pstatix it's not the full code...this is just a part.

Comment: use `for index, item in enumerate(u):`

Comment: res[0] will always return 123. You have to increment res[1] to get the next res element in the list.

Comment: @RonNorris a way to do it automatically for every loop ?

Comment: @Link Dont post partial code. If you came to a mechanic with a car problem, but didnt show up with the car, how can they fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = open(os.path.expanduser('~FOLDER\\numbers.txt'), 'r')
res = txt.read().splitlines()

u = [something]    
for index, item in enumerate(u):
    var['Number : ' + res[index]]
```

More info about enumerate here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: "index" don't have to be initialized above u?

Comment: Index can only be used within the for loop

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the job :

`with open(os.path.expanduser('~FOLDER\\numbers.txt'), 'r') as res:
    for line in res:
        var['Number ': line]`

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11555509/8769830)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to iterate through u and v simultaneously. In this case, you either want to just use a plain index using for loop over a `range`, or you could use `enumerate` as follows:

```
txt = open(os.path.expanduser('~FOLDER\\numbers.txt'), 'r')
res = txt.read().splitlines()

u = [something]    
for index, item in enumerate(u):
    var['Number : ' + res[index]]
```