# Not getting expected o/p for readline code

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline

Can someone please help me why the below readline code is not giving expected result ?

```
f=open('Python_practice/Sample1.txt','r')
while f.readline() != '':
    print(f.readline(),end = '')
f.close()
```

Here - Am getting below o/p ( first and 3rd line is not coming ):
How are you ?
What about you ?

While when I am running below code, I am getting expected o/p.

```
f=open('Python_practice/Sample1.txt','r')
while True:
    data = f.readline()
    if data == '':
        break
    else:
        print(data,end = '')
f.close()
```

Hello!
How are you ?
I am fine, thanks.
What about you ?

```
f=open('Python_practice/Sample1.txt','r')
while f.readline() != '':
    print(f.readline(),end = '')
f.close()
```

I am expecting :
Hello!
How are you ?
I am fine, thanks.
What about you ?

Am getting below o/p ( first and 3rd line is not coming ):
How are you ?
What about you ?

Comment: In the first example, you are calling `f.readline()` twice in every loop and discarding the result of the first while printing the second. This will have the effect of printing every second line.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Abion47 said, the reason it skips every second line is because you run `f.readline()` twice within the same iteration. In other words, you are saying to check if the current line is empty, and if true, read the next line and print it. Below I include a trace of what that loop is doing.

```
----iteration 1----

if "Hello!" is empty
print "How are you ?"

----iteration 2----

if "I am fine thanks" is empty
print "What about you ?"

---iteration 3----

if "" is empty
end
```

As a besides, reading text files like that does not seem to be the best approach. Consider using

```py
with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555468/how-should-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: I am new to python .. Thank you so much for clearing my doubt. It helped.

Comment: @Aditya The proper StackExchange etiquette is to also click the checkmark if an answer correctly solved your problem.