# Python searching a large list speed

Tags: python, list, memory, optimization, text

I have run into a speed issue searching through a very large list. I have a file with a lot of errors and very strange words in it. I am trying to use difflib to find the closest match in a dictionary file I have that has 650,000 words in it. This approach below works really well but is very very slow and I was wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem. This is the code:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
headWordList = [ #This is a list of 650,000 words]


openFile = open("sentences.txt","r")

for line in openFile:
    sentenceList.append[line]

percentage = 0
count = 0

for y in sentenceList:
      if y not in headwordList:

         for x in headwordList:
             m = SequenceMatcher(None, y.lower(), x)

             if m.ratio() > percentage:
                 percentage = m.ratio()

                 word = x

         if percentage > 0.86:        
             sentenceList[count] = word
count=count+1
```

Thanks for the help, software engineering is not even close to my strong suit. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't agree. He's more or less looking for alternative approaches

Comment: This is a data structures problem.

Comment: Did you mean `m = SequenceMatcher(None, y.lower(), x)`

Comment: One thing I can immediately see is to make `headwordList` a set instead of a list, to get better look-up performance for those `in` checks.

Comment: Also you could parallelise this. Of course any serial optimisation is good but ultimately if you break it down into a few threads it may be faster to write it such that it's fast enough like that.

Comment: Is this based on an existing algorithm, or are you sort of hacking something together?  The specific `0.86` makes me think if we know the original problem, we might be able to suggest a better way to do it overall.

Comment: Are you sure it is correct and works? percentage is non decreasing on each step, and counter is incremented only once

Comment: wim,  I need to check every word in the list and compare it using SequenceMatcher. Does making it a set help this? I would have though that it would be the same because you need to check each value.

Comment: @EnglishGrad it will greatly help with `if y not in headwordList:` part

Comment: I think you have an indentation issue as well - `count=count+1` doesn't make any sense where it is.  Can you double-check that everything made it into the question correctly?

Comment: [Everyone else has also overlooked this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) - `This is expensive to compute if get_matching_blocks() or get_opcodes() hasn’t already been called, in which case you may want to try quick_ratio() or real_quick_ratio() first to get an upper bound.` (a thought like this is why I asked about the algorithm being used - an upper-bound on the ratio might be sufficient for the `if` statement in the innermost loop, then only get the true ratio afterwards)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things that might provide some small help:

1) Use the approach in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python) to read through your large file the most efficiently.

2) Change your code from

```
for x in headwordList:
    m = SequenceMatcher(None, y.lower(), 1)
```

to

```
yLower = y.lower()
for x in headwordList:
    m = SequenceMatcher(None, yLower, 1)
```

You're converting each sentence to lower 650,000 times. No need for that.

Answer (score 4):

You should change `headwordList` into a `set`.

The test `word in headwordList` will be very slow.  It must do a string comparison on each word in `headwordList`, one word at a time.  It will take time proportional to the length of the list; if you double the length of the list, you will double the amount of time it takes to do the test (on average).

With a `set`, it always takes the same amount of time to do the `in` test; it doesn't depend on the number of elements in the `set`.  So that will be a huge speedup.

Now, this whole loop can be simplified:

```
     for x in headwordList:
         m = SequenceMatcher(None, y.lower(), x)

         if m.ratio() > percentage:
             percentage = m.ratio()

             word = x

     if percentage > 0.86:        
         sentenceList[count] = word
```

All this does is find the word from `headwordList` that has the highest ratio, and keep it (but only keep it if the ratio is over 0.86).  Here's a faster way to do this.  I'm going to change the name `headwordList` to just `headwords` as I want you to make it be a `set` and not a `list`.

```
def check_ratio(m):
    return m.ratio()

y = y.lower()  # do the .lower() call one time
m, word =  max((SequenceMatcher(None, y, word), word) for word in headwords, key=check_ratio)
percentage = max(percentage, m.ratio())  # remember best ratio
if m.ratio() > 0.86:
    setence_list.append(word)
```

This might seem a bit tricky but it is the fastest way to do this in Python.  We will call the built-in `max()` function to find the `SequenceMatcher` result that has the highest ratio.  First, we build a "generator expression" that tries all the words in `headwords`, calling `SequenceMatcher()` on each.  But when we are done, we also want to know what the word was.  So the generator expression produces tuples, where the first value in the tuple is the `SequenceMatcher` result and the second value is the word.  The `max()` function cannot know that what we care about is the ratio, so we have to tell it that; we do this by making a function that tests what we care about, then passing that function as the `key=` argument.  Now `max()` finds the value with the highest ratio for us.  `max()` consumes all the values produced by the generator expression and returns a single value, which we then unpack into the varaibles `m` and `word`.

In Python, it is best practice to use variable names like `sentence_list` rather than `sentenceList`.  Please see these guidelines: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

It is not good practice to use an incrementing index variable and assign into indexed positions in a list.  Rather, start with an empty list and use the `.append()` method function to append values.

Also, you might do better to build a dictionary of words and their ratios.

Note that your original code seems to have a bug: as soon as any word has a percentage over 0.86, all words are saved in `sentenceList` no matter what their ratio is.  The code I wrote, above, only saves words where the word's own ratio was high enough.

EDIT: This is to answer a question about generator expressions needing to be parenthesized.

Whenever I get that error message, I usually split out the generator expression by itself and assign it to a variable.  Like this:

```
def check_ratio(m):
    return m.ratio()

y = y.lower()  # do the .lower() call one time
genexp = ((SequenceMatcher(None, y, word), word) for word in headwords)
m, word =  max(genexp, key=check_ratio)
percentage = max(percentage, m.ratio())  # remember best ratio
if m.ratio() > 0.86:
    setence_list.append(word)
```

That's what I suggest.  But if you don't mind a complicated line looking even busier, you can simply add an extra pair of parentheses as the error message suggests, so the generator expression is fully parenthesized.  Like so:

```
m, word =  max(((SequenceMatcher(None, y, word), word) for word in headwords), key=check_ratio)
```

Python lets you omit the explicit parentheses around a generator expression when you pass the expression to a function, but only if it is the only argument to that function.  As we are also passing a `key=` argument, we need a fully parenthesized generator expression.

But I think it's easier to read if you split out the genexp on its own line.

EDIT: @Peter Wood pointed out that the documentation suggests reusing a `SequenceMatcher` for speed.  I don't have time to test this, but I think this is the right way to do it.

Happily, the code got simpler!  Always a good sign.

EDIT: I just tested the code.  This code works for me; see if it works for you.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

headwords = [
# This is a list of 650,000 words
# Dummy list:
    "happy",
    "new",
    "year",
]


def words_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                yield word

def _match(matcher, s):
    matcher.set_seq2(s)
    return (matcher.ratio(), s)

ratios = {}
best_ratio = 0

matcher = SequenceMatcher()

for word in words_from_file("sentences.txt"):
    matcher.set_seq1(word.lower())
    if word not in headwords:
        ratio, word =  max(_match(matcher, word.lower()) for word in headwords)
        best_ratio = max(best_ratio, ratio)  # remember best ratio
        if ratio > 0.86:
            ratios[word] = ratio

print(best_ratio)
print(ratios)
```

Comment: Steveha, I find this approach interesting and I am trying to use it but I am getting and error message that says: "generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument"  ...any ideas?

Comment: Also, [the docs suggest reusing a `SequenceMatcher`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects): 'SequenceMatcher computes and caches detailed information about the second sequence, so if you want to compare one sequence against many sequences, use set_seq2() to set the commonly used sequence once and call set_seq1() repeatedly, once for each of the other sequences.'

Answer (score 3):

1) I would store `headwordList` as a set, not a list, allowing for faster access as it is a hashed data structure.

2) You have `sentenceList` defined as a list then attempt to use it as a dictionary with `sentenceList[x] = y`. I would define a different structure specifically for counts.

3) You construct `sentenceList` which doesn't need to be done.

```
for line in file:
   if line not in headwordList...
```

4) You never tokenize `line` which means you store the entire line before the newline character in sentenceList and see if it is in a wordlist

Answer (score 0):

This is a data structures question. What you want to do, is to turn your list into something with faster element lookup speed, for example a binary search tree would work great here: time complexity is only `O (log n)` as opposed to `O (n)` in a list (which is in comparison incredibly fast).

There's a fairly simple explanation here:

http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/balanced.html

But if you are not familiar with tree concepts, you might want to start few chapters earlier:

http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/trees.html

Comment: This is not a useful answer to a Python question.  Python includes several built-ins that can be usefully applied to this question (`set` and `dict`).  @English Grad says that he/she is not an expert software engineer, so a page showing how to implement a data structure is not going to help, and even an expert software developer would be better served by using a Python built-in than by implementing a tree data structure.