# i find the files at the end empty ,python

Tags: python

please in need your help , i wanrt to compy some specific lines from a file to another two ones.
the variables n and p are global .
here is my code :

```
def files():
    i = 1
    X = 1
    f90 = open('C:\Users\Homura\Desktop\python\data90.txt' , 'w')
    f10 = open('C:\Users\Homura\Desktop\python\data10.txt' , 'w')
    f = open('C:\Users\Homura\Desktop\python\TData.txt' , 'r')
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line.startswith('0'):
            while i <= n: # taking 90% of negative tweets and writing them in f90
                f90.write(line)
                i += 1
            while i != n: #putting the rest of the negative tweets ( 10%) in the f10 file 
                f10.write(line)
                i += 1
        elif line.startswith('1'):
            while ( x <= p): # taking 90% of positive tweets and writing them in f90 
                f90.write(line)
                x += 1 
            while (x != p): #putting the rest of the positive tweets ( 10%) in the f10 file
                f10.write(line)
                x += 1                  

    f.close()
    f10.close()
    f90.close()
    return f10 , f90
```

Comment: please explain your problem, what you tried, what you want the program to do, and what do you mean by "compy"?

Comment: s/wanrt /want s/compy/copy ?

Comment: Maybe if you can proide a sample line from your files, we could help you more.

Comment: i'm sorry for the taping errors , i want to copy 90% tweets ( lines begining with 0 or 1 ) to two files f90 and the rest of tweets in a file called f10.

Answer (score 1):

First, a small observation, you have an uppercase `X` and a lowercase `x` - are they supposed to be the same?

```
X = 1
#...
x += 1
```

Next, the chances are the lines do not start with the characters you think they start with.
Consider adding an else to catch neither a `0` or a `1` at the start.

Finally since you say `while True` it's not clear how to while loop will ever terminate, so perhaps it doesn't and the files never get closed. Try just doing for line in file... (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python))

Try this:

```
   for line in f:
        if line.startswith('0'):
            while i <= n: # taking 90% of negative tweets and writing them in f90
                f90.write(line)
                i += 1
            while i != n: #putting the rest of the negative tweets ( 10%) in the f10 file 
                f10.write(line)
                i += 1
        elif line.startswith('1'):
            while ( x <= p): # taking 90% of positive tweets and writing them in f90 
                f90.write(line)
                x += 1 
            while (x != p): #putting the rest of the positive tweets ( 10%) in the f10 file
                f10.write(line)
                x += 1         
        else:
            print "Unmatched line ", line
```

---

**EDIT**

All of the above assumes you have managed to open the input file ok.

Note

> " The backslash () character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed
>   with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use
>   different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences"

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

You use input files with backslashes in:
e.g.

```
f = open('C:\Users\Homura\Desktop\python\TData.txt' , 'r')
```

Try changing this to a raw string

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\Homura\Desktop\python\TData.txt' , 'r')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , but it not working                     File ".\first.py", line 64
    if line.startswith('0'):
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Indentation error often means you have a muddle of tabs and spaces.

Comment: i copy past what u gave me , i had this problem , i dont se that we need an indent , but python knows wayyy better :D

Comment: please, what do you mean by that, i am using notepad +++ i m using tab  for indents

Comment: I used spaces for indents - you need to be consistent.

Comment: In notepad++ replace, select extended, do \t for tab and use 4 spaces - be consistent. Most people use spaces not tabs.

Comment: thank you so much , i did it , but the same problem, no Errors but nothing happens !!! no files have been filled up .