# Python file not opening

Tags: python, file-io

Just trying to do a very standard open and iterate through a file:

```
file = open('test2.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    #first,sec = line.split(',')
    #print "first", first
    print line
```

However, it only prints the last line.

Changing to `file.readline()` solves this problem. Why not the first way?

Comment: You should not reuse the name `file`, but otherwise there's no error demonstrated here.  Do you at any point call something like `fh.readlines()`, next(fh), `list(fh)` or something similar?  The code here isn't indented properly, so mustn't be your actual code.  Also, can you vouch for valid line endings in your input data?

Comment: Strange, works fine as expected on my computer. Is this the exact code?

Comment: That sounds like a line ending problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `readlines`, as has been suggested in other answers. It is [slow](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html)

Instead, do this:

```
with open('test2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       print line
```

The advantage here is that you are not reading the entire file into memory first and then processing. Additionally, by using the `with`, your fill will be automatically closed when you leave that block.

If you need to make your file into a list (as `readlines` does), then make that explicit.

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    lines = list(f)
```

Now `lines` is a list that you can iterate over multiple times.

```
for line in lines:
    print line

for line in lines:
    print "Loop 2 - %s" % (line)
```

Comment: Although my problem was caused by something that couldn't be deduced by the question, this was a very good answer

Answer (score 1):

The first way, that will be unefficient if it comes to bigger files:

```
file = open('test2.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    print line
```

Another way (mentioned in [How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)):

```
with open('a.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
    print line
```

Comment: While not incorrect, this is unnecessary, and loads the entire file into memory.  That might not matter, but it might be critical.