# Importing a particular line in Python from a text file

Tags: python

I am a newby to Python. 
I have a source file which has 10 rows in it. 
Using Python I want to import 1 particular line to a new file.

Please let me know how I should proceed with this.

Comment: how do you import one line to a new file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) if you know the number of line you are after:

```
import linecache
a_line = linecache.getline('/tmp/file.txt', 4)

# save it to new file
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
          f.write(a_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a "for" loop to count line by line, until you're at the line you want. After that, save a copy of that line onto a variable, in this case "stringTemp":

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as inputStream: # open a file.txt onto a stream variable
stringTemp = ""  # initialize an empty string, where you'll save the line you want
particularLineNumber = 3
count = 0      # a variable to keep count of which line you are on
for line in inputStream:   # "for each thing in the stream variable, save it onto "line"
    if count == particularLineNumber - 1: # if we are on the line we want...
        stringTemp = line                 # ... save it to stringTemp
    count = count + 1         # if we are NOT on the line we want, increase the counter


# ... write the variable stringTemp onto another file ...
```

I'm assuming you want your line numbers as "1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 9, 10". If you decide to start at 0 ("0,1,2,3...10"), then remove the "- 1" on "if count == particularLineNumber - 1"

Answer (score 1):

This will read the whole file at once:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

With all the lines read, you can do whatever you like with it.

This will read the file one line at a time:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

This has been answered many times, though:

[How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)

[How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)