# Merge huge files by code with unique check

Tags: python, file-io, merge, hashtable

I have many huge (>40Gb) text files, which contains same lines into one file and in other files. I need to merge this files under Windows into one big file without line dublicates.

I want to do this by Python, due to fast hashtable.

As I understand I need:

1. Sort each file
2. Open each file and read by line until end

smth like:

```
sort(file1)
sort(file2)

openRead(file1)
openRead(file2)
openWrite(file3)
string previousLine = ""
string line1 = read(file1)
string line2 = read(file2)

do {
    if (line1 > line2) {
       if (previousLine != line2) {
           write(line2, file3)
           previousLine = line2
       }
       line2 = read(file2)
    } else {
        if (line2 > line1) {
            if (previousLine != line1) {
                write(line1, file3)
                previousLine = line1
            }
            line1 = read(file1)
        } else {
            if (previousLine != line1) {
                write(line1, file3)
                previousLine = line1
            }
            line1 = read(file1)
            line2 = read(file2)
        }
    }
} while (!Eof(file1) && !Eof(file2))

readBiggerFileToEndAndWriteLinesTo(file3)
```

Is this idea correct? Or Python propose more faster solution? (I have only 32Gb memory). How can I write this solution in Python?

Comment: Do you actually need the sorting procedure?

Comment: @DanielePantaleone if you can propose faster working solution without sort - no, I didn't need it.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Attempt it yourself, and then, if you run into a specific issue, ask a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the merge result fits into memory (since there are duplicated lines it may be the case), you can create a `set` into which add all the lines you are reading from the file: the `set` will ensure not to have duplicated strings. 
To read the file you can do:

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        # add the line in the set
```

No need to worry about reading large files here (more reading: [How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python))

If the data doesn't fit into memory (so it's more than 32GB, well actually more than something less than 32GB), you would need to split the whole process into chunks.