# Remove a column of text

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python, but I have some scripting experience in other languages. I'm trying to write a script that reads a text file with data formatted like this:

```
1    52345
2    53
3    -654
4    2342
```

and print it out like this:

```
52345,
53,
-654,
2342,
```

So I want to remove the first column and whitespace and add a comma at the end.

This is what I have so far, but it seems like I'm trying to use string methods on a file object.

```
def remove_first_column(text):
    splitString = text.split(' ')

    splitString.pop(0)


    finalString = "  ".join(
        [item.strip() for item in splitString])

    return finalString

def main():
    print "Type the filename:"
    file_again = raw_input("> ")
    txt = open(file_again)
    for line in txt.split("\n"):
        print(remove_first_column(line))  #py2.5  print remove_first_column(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get an exception saying that "AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read large file, line by line in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you open a file using `open` function, it returns you a file object, you can iterate over the file object (to get each line) ,but you cannot use `file.split('\n')` , etc.

Try doing -

```
for line in txt:
    print(remove_first_column(line))  #py2.5  print remove_first_column(line)
```

You do not need the `split` , iterating over the `txt` file would return each line in each iteration.

Also, inside your function, you are doing - `splitString = text.split(' ')` , if the string has multiple spaces in between the two columns, this can lead to many empty string elements like - `['1', '', '', '', '52345']` (though that does not cause issue in your particular code) , just letting you know , you can do - `splitString = text.split()` , to split by all whitespaces , (it would result in a list like - `['1','52345']`

Answer (score 1):

`txt` is a file object, not a string. You can try

```
for line in txt:
```

instead of

```
for line in txt.split("\n"):
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot split a file object:

```
for line in txt:
```