# stuck on basic regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Task: To find all the numbers in a text file and compute the sum of it.

Link to file(if required) : http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt

```
name = raw_input("Enter your file: ")
if len(name) < 1: name = "sample.txt"

try: 
    open(name)
except:
    print "Please enter a valid file name."
    exit()

import re
lst = list()
for line in name:
    line = line.strip()  #strip() instead of rstrip() as there were space before line as well
    stuff = re.findall("[0-9]+", line)
    print stuff               # i tried to trace back and realize it prints empty list so problem should be here
    stuff = int(stuff[0])     # i think this is wrong as well 
    lst.append(stuff)
    sum(lst)

print sum(lst)
```

Can someone tell me where did I go wrong ? sorry for any formatting errors and thanks for the help

I have also tried:

```
\s[0-9]+\s
.[0-9]+.
```

Comment: Your first regex is correct (you could even change it to `(\d+)`, however, you need a global modifier and a capturing group to save the found numbers. See [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mA9jV8/2).

Comment: No, OP does not have to use any capture groups. `re.findall` is performing a global search. I get *IndexError: list index out of range* error.

Comment: @stribizhev: Ok, did not know that the re module handles this automatically. I'm more of a PHP guy where `preg_match_all()` needs capturing groups.

Comment: @Jan: `preg_match_all` does not require capturing groups either :)

Comment: Where do you read from the file? At the moment `name` only contains the actual *filename* and not the *content*, thus line does not hold the content you're after.

Comment: Shortcut: it should be 597873. No program needed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to:

```
lst = []
with open(name) as f:
    for line in f:
        stuff = [lst.append(int(x)) for x in re.findall("[0-9]+", line.strip())]
print sum(lst)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/TCUbn2)

The problem was that you tried to parse an empty string in the first place. When parsing to int and appending to the list (declared with `lst = []`) inside *comprehension*, you avoid messing with empty output and the list you get is flattened automatically.

Also, you need to actually read the file in. *"The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The `for line in f` treats the file object `f` as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files."* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/3832970))

Comment: I agree to you on this one but if this is the OP's original code (and not just edited somehow) where does he *actually* read from the file? At the moment, the file is only opened but nothing happens afterwards so `line` is always empty.

Comment: I mean this should be used when the file is actually read of course.

Comment: I was just thinking loud, maybe the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Jan: Thank you for spotting that, I was just focusing on the actual issue with parsing the contents and overlooked file reading issue.