# Python - Struck up with logic ! How do you convert a text file like this to a CSV file?

Tags: python, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a text file which has the data in the form of column : row. I would like to load this text file into python and convert it into csv or an excel file and save it in local desktop. Anyone have a logic? Kindly share your answers. Thanks in advance. Here goes a sample of my data in the text file,

```
Name of the Property : North Kensington Upcycling Store and Cafe
Availability : Now 
Interest Level : 74 people are looking right now
Area :  1,200 sqft
Retail Type  : No
Bar & Restaurant Type  : No
Event Type  : Yes
Shop Share Type  : No
Unique Type  : No
Price Per Day : £360
Price Per Week : £1,260
Price Per Month : £5,460
Price Per Quarter : £16,380
Price Per Year : £65,520
[Latitude, Longitude] : [51.5235108631773, -0.206594467163086]
Name of the Property : Old Charlton Pub
Availability : Now 
Interest Level : 20 people are looking right now
Area :  1,250 sqft
Retail Type  : No
Bar & Restaurant Type  : Yes
Event Type  : No
Shop Share Type  : No
Unique Type  : No
Price Per Day : £70
Price Per Week : £490
Price Per Month : £2,129
Price Per Year : £25,550
[Latitude, Longitude] : [51.4926332979245, 0.0449645519256592]
```

This is the code that I am trying,

```
import pandas
txt_file = r"patty.txt"
txt = open(txt_file, "r")
txt_string = txt.read()
txt_lines = txt_string.split("\n")
txt_dict = {}

for txt_line in txt_lines:
    print(txt_line)
    k,v = txt_line.split(" : ")
    k = k.strip()
    v = v.strip()
    if k in txt_dict:
        list = txt_dict.get(k)
    else:
        list = []
    list.append(v)
    txt_dict[k]=list
print (pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(txt_dict, orient="index"))
```

and getting this error :- **k,v = txt_line.split(" : ") ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

Comment: Read File, Parse File, Write Data To CSV.

Comment: @MooingRawr but I do have some missing values, say in this case - I don't have the Price Per Quarter data in the second set.

Comment: @MooingRawr Please can you write a sample code for it. Am a beginner and just getting along.

Comment: Learning how to code is best if you try it out, it's like swimming, sure we can show you how to swim and you can copy us, but if you never try you will never be a good swimmer. So how about you read up on how to do things, give it a try, and then come back to us when you failed; we will gladly help you out that way. Lack of effort is generally frowned upon here anyways.

Comment: Ya I understand. I am trying to get on with things. Thanx anyways

Comment: Your line doesn't contain a colon, for that error... By the way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You will use pandas, which you will import. It allows you to read .txt data (dont be confused, this is possible although the function is called "read.csv()"

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('text.txt', sep = ':', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

df.to_csv('text.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep=';')
```

Feel free to read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for getting details on the keywords such as "sep" or "encoding" (which is required here since there is a pound symbol"

Comment: Thanks for that. But the output isn't a structured one. What I am looking for is a normal structured one. With the values on the left side of : as Column name and right side of : as a Row and when there are missing values like Price Per Quarter, I want it to have a NA over there. Such a complex one ! :(

Comment: Step by step is the way to go. I am merely trying to point a direction rather than solving your work/homework

Comment: Cool, Cool !! Thanks. Let me work on this and I will get back if I do get struck somewhere.

Comment: Thats the spirit!

Comment: My Idea of doing this was to, load this data as a text file and load another CSV File with only the required column names and probably parse them together. Will it work ?

Comment: unless you provide some code and specific the question regarding your code and the error it yields, the question will be closed.

Comment: Sorry if i Frustrated you. I have tried the code that I updated in the question. Got an error with the final step. Can you rectify that ? Thanks

Comment: You did not at all frustrate me :) Thank you for your consideration. I am only warning you since other members of this community consider your question to be of poor quality - which is why it has been put "on hold"