# reading the first N lines in a file without opening it (Python)

Tags: python, text, tail, head

I have a Python script which needs to read a section of a very large text file, starting at line N and ending at N+X.
I don't want to use "open('file')", because that will write the entire thing to the memory, which will both take too long, and waste too much memory.
My script runs on a Unix machine, so I currently use the native head and tail functions, i.e.:

```
section = subprocess.check_output('tail -n-N {filePath} | head -n X')
```

but is feels like there must be a smarter way of doing it..
is there a way to get lines N through N+X of a text file in Python without opening the entire file?

Thanks!

Comment: *“I don't want to use "open('file')", because that will write the entire thing to the memory, which will both take too long, and waste too much memory.”* That is not what `open` does; use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) works well for doing this:

```
from itertools import islice

N = 2
X = 5

with open('large_file.txt') as f_input:
    for row in islice(f_input, N-1, N+X):
        print row.strip()
```

This skips over all of the initial lines and just returns the lines you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is located here: [How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

> The with statement handles opening and closing the file, including if
>   an exception is raised in the inner block. The for line in f treats
>   the file object f as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO
>   and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.