# Python file io buffering

Tags: python, file, io, buffer

I need to iterate over the lines of a couple of text files a couple of times.
This is currently done with multiple

```
with open("file.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:
        # do something
```

Although performance is not an issue yet, I'd like to read the files only once into an `io.StringIO` buffer and then work with that.

Python `io` docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

  - https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase

    - https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase

      - https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

This is a working snippet

```
import io
sio = io.StringIO( open("file.txt").read() )
for line in sio:
    print(line)
sio.seek(0)
for line in sio:
    print(line)
sio.close()
```

or wrapping it in a [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)

```
import io
with io.StringIO( open("file.txt").read() ) as sio:
    for line in sio:
        print(line)
    sio.seek(0)
    for line in sio:
        print(line)
    #sio.close()
```

Questions

1. Is this a "good" way of doing it, what are alternatives?
2. What happens to the file object used to read the file (there's no way to explicitly `close()` it this way)?
3. Where can I read more about Python's io buffering (I think I read something about Python optimizing multiple file accesses by buffering automatically)?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is already the right way. Quoting from this answer: [How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)

> The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The `for line in f` treats the file object `f` as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.

Comment: Yes, but my questions are about processing a file _multiple_ times. Should it be `open()`ed multiple times? Also there are no references about the buffering.