# Syntax error on a while as loop

Tags: python, loops, syntax

I am trying to download a web page with python 2.7.13 and go line by line to analyze it. From memory and from searching around, I found that the following code snippet would be sufficient to go line by line:

```
 with s as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

The variable `s` is defined by a file.read() and the file is defined by urllib2 opening a specified url. Unfortunately, when I run the script, I get this syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 12, in <module>
    with s as f:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

I'm honestly dumbfounded of what I did wrong and it would be appreciated to gain insight about my mistake.

Comment: Which version of Python takes `as` in the condition of a `while` loop?

Comment: Where did you get this code snippet from?

Comment: The 'as' keyword is for import statements and exceptions. In this case, you should just be able to loop directly over the file object with your `for line in f:`, no need for a while loop.

Comment: Your mistake is simple: that is not valid Python, and I don't now what you think you were accomplishing.

Comment: I found the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/4415644

Comment: I'm foggy today, I put while instead of with. I'll accommodate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found that the following code snippet would be sufficient to go line by line:

It is, but for **file objects** as in

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
```

> The variable s is defined by a file.read()

That's a string, and can't be used in the `with`.

> and the file is defined by urllib2 opening a specified url.

That's a file-**like** object, but happens to be iterable

> I am trying to download a web page with python 2.7.13 and go line by line to analyze it.

No useful information can be gathered from iterating lines of a website. (at least (X)HTML, JSON, etc)

Try using BeautifulSoup or XPath

Comment: Alright, I just remembered I could split the lines by "\n" and the loop through the list. Like I said, I'm very foggy today. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can, but unless your website only contains multi line text, then parsing HTML makes more sense