# Skip a long line when reading a big file to avoid MemoryError?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, bigdata

I need to scan two large txt files (both about **100GB, 1 billion rows**, several columns) and take out a certain column (write to new files). The files look like this

```
ID*DATE*provider
1111*201101*1234
1234*201402*5678
3214*201003*9012
...
```

My Python script is

```
N100 = 10000000   ## 1% of 1 billion rows
with open("myFile.txt") as f:
    with open("myFile_c2.txt", "a") as f2:
        perc = 0
        for ind, line in enumerate(f):   ## <== MemoryError
            c0, c1, c2  = line.split("*")
            f2.write(c2+"\n")
            if ind%N100 == 0: 
                print(perc, "%")
                perc+=1
```

Now the above script run well for one file but stuck for another one at 62%. The error message says `MemoryError` for `for ind, line in enumerate(f):`. I tried several times in different server with different RAM, the error is the same, all at 62%. I waited hours to monitor the RAM and it exploded to 28GB (total=32GB) when 62%. So I guess in that file there is a line that somehow too long (maybe not ended with `\n` ?) and thus Python stuck when trying reading it to the RAM.

So my question is, before I go to my data provider, what can I do to detect the error line and somehow get around/skip reading it as one huge line? Appreciate any suggestions!

EDIT:

The file, starting from the 'error line', might be all messed together with another line separator rather than `\n`. If that's the case, can I detect the line sep and continue extracting the columns I want, rather than throwing away them? Thanks!

Comment: If you monitor the process for the first 62%, does memory use grow steadily? You might have a memory leak unrelated to line parsing.

Comment: You can use the `readline` method on the file object, which accepts a maximum line length.

Comment: Actually no. It's all fine until somewhere near 62%

Comment: then drop the "by line" approach and read character by character, counting the "*" and the linefeeds.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre or some reasonable "chunk".

Comment: i vote for the yield approach like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python

Comment: You don't need to drop to processing characters; as I said before, you can use `readline` to keep using lines but truncate long lines to a suitable length.

Comment: @JasonLou To use a different character as a newline you may as well start processing the raw character stream, but perhaps you can repair your data by preprocessing the file and replacing the messed up character with `\n`?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin  what do you mean by "replacing the messed up character with `\n` "?

Comment: @JasonLou From your edit, you say that there is a line where the newlines are missing, and are substituted with some other type of line separator character. Couldn't you just replace this non-standard line separator character with `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (untested) code might solve your problem. It limits its input to 1,000,000 bytes per read, to reduce its maximum memory consumption.

Note that this code returns the *first* million characters from each line. There are other possibilities for how to deal with a long line:

- return the first million characters
- return the last million characters
- skip the line entirely, optionally logging that, or
- raise an exception.

```
#UNTESTED
def read_start_of_line(fp):
    n = int(1e6)
    tmp = result = fp.readline(n)
    while tmp and tmp[-1] != '\n':
        tmp = fp.readline(n)
    return result

N100 = 10000000   ## 1% of 1 billion rows
with open("myFile.txt") as f:
    with open("myFile_c2.txt", "a") as f2:
        perc = 0
        for ind, line in enumerate(iter(lambda: read_start_of_line(f), '')):
            c0, c1, c2  = line.split("*")
            f2.write(c2+"\n")
            if ind%N100 == 0:
                print(perc, "%")
                perc+=1
```

Comment: Can you explain what does `while tmp and tmp[-1] != '\n':` do? It seems the 1,000,000 bytes will cut good line into pieces, then how can I get the column I want? Thanks

Comment: what if c2 is at the end of the line? maybe keeping the _end_ of the line would be better. it depends on what's in the OP "big line"

Comment: @JasonLou - That expression controls the continuation of the `while` loop. It keeps reading, and throwing away data, until it finally reads a newline, i.e. until it finally reads the entire long line.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - You are right. My presumption is that `c2` is within the first 1,000,000 characters. I'll document that.

Comment: since the line is split in 3 parts (unpacking requires that), if c2 is within the first 10000000 chars then it's truncated by your method. If it's in the last 10000000 chars there's a chance that c0 or/and c1 are truncated, but not c2 (else: unpack error). I would have read block by block and splitted manually. But that's a big effort to write such code. Interesting question, but tedious work at answering this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - You are right, returning the last million is guaranteed to be wrong. I wasn't looking at OP's use case, just thinking generally I'd want to throw away the trailing, not leading data. Hopefully OP can build on what I've got.

Comment: you cannot know what's in the line, so your answer is as good at it can be.

Comment: @Robᵩ  Yes yours should be the best answer to now. Can you see my new EDIT in the question?

Comment: @JasonLou - I can't think of any way to recognize a new line separator on the fly. At that point, I think I'd open the file in my favorite text editor and try to fix the file manually.

Comment: @Robᵩ  Yes, and that's why I'm now contacting the data provider now... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a maximum chunk size solves the problem of overflowing memory, while still allowing you to process the entire file. The following generator functions should help you do it:

```py
def chunks(f, bufsize):
  while True:
    chunk = f.readline(bufsize)
    if not chunk:
      break
    yield chunk
    if chunk[-1] == "\n":
      break

def lines(path, bufsize):
  with open(path) as f:
    pos = -1
    while f.tell() > pos:
      pos = f.tell()
      c = chunks(f, bufsize)
      yield c
      for _ in c:
        pass
```

Here is an example of how to read only the first 20 characters from each line:

```
import itertools

for i, line in enumerate(lines("./core/scrape.js", 10)):
  print(i, end=": ")
  print(''.join(itertools.islice(line, 2)).rstrip())
```

Output looks something like:

```
0: /**
1:  * Document scraper/
2:  *
3:  * @author Branden H
4:  * @license MIT
5:  *
6:  */
7:
8: var promise = requir
9: var fs = promise.pro
10: var _ = require("lod
11: var util = require("
12: const path = require
```