# Read huge file using a 'for' loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge file, abc.txt, and wanted to read line by line, not all at once. I can do it as below:

```
filename="c:\abc.txt"
with open (filename, "r") as fb:
    for content in fb:
        # Do something ....
```

Here I am not understanding one thing. As you see, "fb" is a file pointer over here. How is the "for" loop processing the pointer directly internally even without using any readline or read function?

I just wanted to know how the `for` loop is working here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/4794459

Comment: 1. `fb` is not a "file pointer". It is a file object. 2. File objects are generators that are built to yield a file content line by line when they are iterated over (either by a loop or with the `next` function).   See https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-file-object and https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a 'pointer' in Python.

`fb` is a *file object*. File objects in Python are a container type and  generators. They implementg the *iterator protocol* and when looped over (for instance using a for-loop), it produces individual lines from the file that you opened.

If you want to try and see what is happening under the hood, try this in a REPL for instance:

```
f = open("sometextfileyouhave.txt", "r")
file_iter = iter(f)
print(next(file_iter))
print(next(file_iter))
print(next(file_iter))
print(next(file_iter))
# ...
```

or even shorter:

```
f = open("sometextfileyouhave.txt", "r")
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
# ...
```