# How to find the number of lines in a document

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that reads a document, and counts how many times a certain letter *x* appears in each row and inserts it into an array. After that, it will return whichever number appeared the most in the array. Here is what I have so far:

```
def LetterNumberCount(Letter):
    document = open ('magazine.in', 'r')
    letterOccurs = []
    for (Number of Lines): #Here is my problem
        line = document.readLine()
        letterOccurs.extend(line.count(Letter))
    return max(letterOccurs)
```

I need help finding the number of lines in the magazine. Is there a function to find the number of lines in something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/1531971 and keep track of the line count as you read them?

Comment: But I want it to be as efficient as possible

Comment: No you don't. you want it to be _correct_ and _functional_ first. Only then, if it is necessary, do you worry about efficiency. _Anyway_ the example I gave you is classic Python and is efficient as it needs to be.

Comment: Uh but I need python

Comment: Oh the thing you gave me wa's python

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop `if line=null: break` . Generally after the last line the document will return null.

Answer (score 0):

the code below should work for you. It returns the line which includes given letter more than any other line.

If you want to return the count of letter in that line, simply return `max_count`.

```
def LetterNumberCount(letter):
    document = open('magazine.in', 'r')
    max_count = 0
    max_count_line = None
    for line in document.readlines():
       if line.count(letter) > max_count:
          max_count = line.count(letter)
          max_count_line = line
    return max_count_line
```

Comment: I want to know which number appears most often out of all of the lines