# How to use loop in Python to extract words (second and third in the line) from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several `txt` files, that contain first and last name of the authors.
Here are two examples among about thirty (**that do not contain the same number of authors**).

authors1.txt

```
AU  - Jordan, M. 
AU  - Thomson, J.J.  
AU  - Einstein, A.  
AU  - Tesla, N.
```

authors3.txt

```
AU  - Agassi, A.
AU  - Herbert, P.H.
AU  - Agut, R.B.
```

I want to extract the last and first name of the authors for each file.
Since I am a beginner in Python, I wrote a script (more or less suitable).

```
with open('authors3.txt', 'rb') as f:
    textfile_temp = f.read()

#o_author1 
o_author1 = textfile_temp.split('AU  - ')[1]
L_name1  = o_author1.split(",")[0]
F_name1  = o_author1.split(",")[1]
print(L_name1)
print(F_name1)

#o_author2 
o_author2 = textfile_temp.split('AU  - ')[2]
L_name2  = o_author2.split(",")[0]
F_name2  = o_author2.split(",")[1]
print(L_name2)
print(F_name2)

#o_author3 
o_author3 = textfile_temp.split('AU  - ')[3]
L_name3  = o_author3.split(",")[0]
F_name3  = o_author3.split(",")[1]
print(L_name3)
print(F_name3)
```

my result is:

```
Agassi
 A.

Herbert
 P.H.

Agut
 R.B.
```

My question: Is it possible to write a script with a loop, knowing that the files `authors#.txt`, don't each contain the same number of authors?

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, wouldn't a [simple for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-a-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python) work?

Comment: Hi @Sean Breckenridge, I'm going to try.

Comment: What is the problem? You just don't know how many lines are in the file? Or maybe you want to iterate 3 files together and they have different sizes?

Comment: Yes I do not know how many lines exist in the authors.txt file. each file has different authors.

Comment: I want to iterate n (30 files) files together with different sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the files in your current (or any other) directory by using `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()`. After you've obtained a list of author text files, you can simply loop through them with a simple for loop.

Hint: [for-looping over a file object will yield you one line at a time](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), until it reaches end of the file - this is also memory efficient, as it only reads one line at a time to memory, instead of loading the entire file contents to your memory.

If you abstract your author name getting to a function, you can then simplify your code to something like this:

```
import os

def get_author(line):
    name = line.strip().split('AU  - ')[1]
    firstname, lastname = name.split(',')
    return firstname, lastname

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    # You probably want a more fancy way of detecting author files
    files = [f for f in files if f.startswith('authors') and f.endswith('.txt')]

    authors = []
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as fd:
            for line in fd:
                authors.append(get_author(line))
    print(authors)
```

`authors` at the end of the script will be a list containing tuples - each tuple consisting of the first and last name of your author.

Answer (score 3):

Using a simple `for-loop`

**Demo:**

```
authors_firstName = []
authors_lastName = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for i in infile.readlines():
        val = i.strip().split("-")[-1].strip().split(",")   #str.strip to remove any leading or trailing space, split by "-"
        authors_firstName.append(val[0])
        authors_lastName.append(val[1])
print(authors_firstName)
print(authors_lastName)
```

**Output:**

```
['Jordan', 'Thomson', 'Einstein', 'Tesla', 'Agassi', 'Herbert', 'Agut']
[' M.', ' J.J.', ' A.', ' N.', ' A.', ' P.H.', ' R.B.']
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read your file line by line, let's say,

```
with open('authors1.txt', 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# lines = ["AU - Jordan, M.", "AU - Thomson, J.J.", "AU - Einstein, A.", "AU  - Tesla, N."]

for line in lines:
    o_author1 = line.split('AU  - ')[1]
    L_name1  = o_author1.split(",")[0]
    F_name1  = o_author1.split(",")[1]
    print(L_name1)
    print(F_name1)

Jordan
 M.
Thomson
 J.J.
Einstein
 A.
Tesla
 N.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rough on my Python, so I'll give you some pseudocode:

```
lines = file.ReadAll()

for line in lines
    parts = line.split("-,")
    print parts[1], parts[2]
```

And that's it.  Read the entire file into a variable, iterate over each line and extract the parts.

Or, basically do what @Rakesh suggested =)