# How to read line when input is pipped

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

so in my linux terminal I type `python3 main.py input.txt > output.txt`

input.txt contains:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is another line
```

How do I go through this line by line and print out each line so my `output.txt` looks like the output below? Essentially, I'm just asking how do I read this like by line? I can't use `fopen` since I am making `input.txt` like my stdin

```
This is line 1
---
This is line 2
---
This is another line
---
```

---

My question is different from the rest because here I am not opening a file using `open()`. I am pipping the stdin input as `input.txt`. As you can see in the command `input.txt > output.txt`. So I cannot use open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a large file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line)

Comment: I see your edit, but you're confused. `input.txt` is an argument. `output.txt` is connected to stdout. If you wanted to connect `input.txt` to stdin, you would write `< input.txt`.

Comment: @wjandrea No it isn't. You aren't being given the file as an argument. I cant use `sys.argv` because my command is `python3 main.py input.txt > output.txt`. Notice the `>` in the command

Comment: @wjandrea well when I use `sys.argv` it doesn't have `input.txt` in it. It just has `main.py`

Comment: With the command line you gave, `sys.argv` will be `['main.py', 'input.txt']`.

Answer (score 0):

With this command line, `python3 main.py input.txt > output.txt`, this will do what you want:

```
import sys

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
    print('---')
```

However, you have your shell syntax confused. You're expecting `input.txt` to be connected to stdin, but that would be written `python3 main.py < input.txt > output.txt` (note the less-than sign `<`). Then your `main.py` would look like this:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
    print('---')
```

Here I'm using [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) to iterate over each line of stdin.

By the way, `fileinput` can get a list of filenames from `sys.argv`, so this would also work for the command line `python3 main.py input.txt > output.txt`.