# How to efficiently sort values from CSV file into multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have a very large CSV file with the following structure:

```
category,value
A,1
A,4
B,2
A,1
B,3
...
```

What I need are two lists. The first list contains all values from category `A`, the seconds list contains all values from category `B`.

A working solution:

```
import csv

list_a = []
list_b = []

with open('my_file.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for line in reader:
        if line['category'] == 'A':
            list_a.append(line['value'])
        if line['category'] == 'B':
            list_b.append(line['value'])
```

Since the CSV file is so large, I would like to avoid the expensive `append` calls. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: have you tried using `pandas`?

Comment: In my experience, `pandas` eats memory for breakfast ... the CSV file is 400MB large and I am afraid the overhead of creating a `pandas.DataFrame` would be huge.

Comment: you can process large data files in chunks if memory is an issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: the pythonic way with least overhead https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/8560382, Consider using queue instead of list?

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
list_a = df.loc[df['category']=='A', 'value'].values.tolist()
list_b = df.loc[df['category']=='B', 'value'].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to apply `collections.defaultdict` in your case.
Though it implies one `.append` call (accumulating lists for each category), it would be much convenient container in potential cases where there could be more than 2 categories. The dict will allow you to keep values for **any** number of categories:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    category_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for line in reader:
        category_dict[line['category']].append(line['value'])
```

Sample output:

```
print(category_dict['A'])   # ['1', '4', '1']
print(category_dict['B'])   # ['2', '3']
```