# Split text into chapters and store it in txt files

Tags: python

I have a .txt file called `book.txt` that I want to divide into multiple .txt files (one per chapter). I would like to end up having .txt files whose names refer to those chapters. For example, if `book.txt` has 20 chapters, I would end up with `1.txt`, `2.txt`, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
import re
book = #I don't know how to import the book.txt file here

chapters = re.split("Chapter ", book, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
for chapter in chapters:
    #Code to write a new .txt file with each element from the list I created using the number after 'Chapter' as the name for the .txt file.
```

As you can see, I'm stuck at importing my `book.txt` file and at creating the new txt files. I'm fairly new to Python, so let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: Have you done any research? Reading text files is a popular topic, there are plenty of resources available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a large file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line). And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file

Comment: So you want to `open` a file?

Comment: Does this help https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

Comment: it's not just about opening a file, it's about creating multiple files and using the number of chapters as file names...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works for me:

```py
import re
book = open("book.txt", "r") #Here we open the book, in this case it is called book.txt
book = str(book.read()) #this is now assigning book the value of book.txt, not just the location
chapters = re.split("Chapter ", book, flags = re.IGNORECASE) #Finds all the chapter markers in the book and makes a list of all the chapters
chapters.pop(0) # Removes the first item in list as this is ""
for i in range(1, len(chapters)+1): #Loops for the number of chapters in the book, starting at chapter 1
    writeBook = open("{}.txt".format(i), "w+") #Opens a book with the name of i, if it does not exist, it creates one
    writeBook.write(chapters[i-1]) #Overwrites what is written in the book with the same chapter in the list
    writeBook.close() #Finally, it closes the text file
```

Please Note: this will not work with a book that has a prologue as it will just remove them from the list of chapters.

Comment: i got this error:     writeBook = open("{}.txt", format(i), "w+")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: I have edited the code, try it again now.