# Reading multiple lines from text file

Tags: python

The goal for my project is to count all the characters in a text file.  My code seems to work, but seems it will only ready the first line of code from the file and nothing else.  I can easily do it in java, but we are required to use python and I have very little experience working with python

my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

from collections import Counter

with open ('myFile', "r") as myfile:
   data=myfile.readlines()

counter = Counter(lines)

print (counter['a'])
print (counter['b'])
print (counter['c'])
print (counter['d'])
print (counter['e'])
print (counter['f'])
print (counter['g'])
print (counter['h'])
print (counter['i'])
print (counter['j'])
print (counter['k'])
print (counter['l'])
print (counter['m'])
print (counter['n'])
print (counter['o'])
print (counter['p'])
print (counter['q'])
print (counter['r'])
print (counter['s'])
print (counter['t'])
print (counter['u'])
print (counter['v'])
print (counter['w'])
print (counter['x'])
print (counter['y'])
print (counter['z'])
```

Comment: Your code is reading the lines (not characters) of the file to a variable called ``data``, but the counter operates on an undefined variable called ``lines``. This code will definitely not work. If you have some code that "seems to work", please post it alongside some example input to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Many examples of this on the net. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/10682164) answer.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This is a topic on which there is plenty of information available, what is different about this particular case?

Comment: Welcome @mateo8, in your code, you can print(data) to see what you are actually getting. A simple and not so clever way is to loop through the lines and count each character. Of course, there are many cleverer ways in python to do that without looping.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `lines` is from your code, you are assigning the list containing lines from the text into `data` variable. If you want to read the whole text as a single string, then just use `read()` method.

```
from collections import Counter

with open ('myFile', "r") as myfile:
   data = myfile.read()

counter = Counter(data)

print (counter['a'])
print (counter['b'])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the code I posted was from two editors I had open at the same time with the same version number, which caused the errors.  I have fixed that (new complete code is below) and is "working" I need to check it against my java code results.  I have included the results of the code

```
import pandas as pd

from collections import Counter



data = open('myFile.txt').read()
data.lower()
print (data)


counter = Counter(data)

print (counter['a'])
print (counter['b'])
print (counter['c'])
print (counter['d'])
print (counter['e'])
print (counter['f'])
print (counter['g'])
print (counter['h'])
print (counter['i'])
print (counter['j'])
print (counter['k'])
print (counter['l'])
print (counter['m'])
print (counter['n'])
print (counter['o'])
print (counter['p'])
print (counter['q'])
print (counter['r'])
print (counter['s'])
print (counter['t'])
print (counter['u'])
print (counter['v'])
print (counter['w'])
print (counter['x'])
print (counter['y'])
print (counter['z'])
```

results from my updated code:

```
28042
3064
9280
12192
45763
3434
5143
3523
24633
1107
328
16641
8817
23809
18195
9202
3611
23139
25219
25990
19636
5302
465
1396
1257
473
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
file = open("myFile.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
number_of_characters = len(data)
print('Number of characters in text file : {}'.format(number_of_characters))
file.close()
```

Comment: Would like to know why this comment got downvoted? The user clearly wanted a method to count all of the characters inside of the text file?

Comment: The question code shows counting individual letters is desired, not the total of characters. Manually closing files instead of using ``with`` is bad practice, as it may leave files open indefinitely. There is no need to read the entire file into memory at once, reading line-wise or in other increments also works on very large files.

Comment: Sure, totally agree with the use of "with" as a context manager. It wasn't entirely clear to me that the user wanted to do this on a line by line basis; the first sentence was "The goal for my project is to count all the characters in a text file." - I thereby merely provided a basic solution. Thanks anyway!