# How to increment from text file?

Tags: python

I'm new in python and i don't know how I can use increment to print the items from text file line by line. I don't want to print them all at once

This is my code:

```
with open('Users.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    Usernames = file.readlines()
print(Usernames = Usernames +1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a large file - line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to print line-by-line:

```
import time
with open('Users.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The above code will wait 1 second after printing each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('Users.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line, end='')
```

You need the `end=''` on the `print` because the lines will already have a newline character append to them.

Comment: y i know this will print all the lines from text file all at once ,  but i want to increment by example if Username == 'Jax': 
     pla pla pla 
     Username +=1 
i want like that but it doesn't work with me