# Parse data line by line in python until EOF

Tags: python

I need to parse a ton of host names into a yaml file.

so far my code looks like this

```
hostname = input.txt

s = (f"{hostname}: \n"
        f"  hostname: {hostname}\n"
        f"  nodename: {hostname}\n"
        f"  username: rundeck\n"
        f"  tags: 'rundeck'\n")

print(s)
```

I have a massive txt file that looks something like

```
hostname1
hostname2
hokjdlaskdsfh4
abcdef8
```

that kind of thing,
I want to insert each line into the `{hostname}` variable in the text.
And each line will result in a new "paragraph" Which I can then > into output.txt

forming a large file with all of the yaml code properly parsed.
Each "output" in the output.yml file will look something like

```
hostname1: 
  hostname: hostname2
  nodename: hostname2
  username: rundeck
  tags: 'rundeck'


abcdef: 
  hostname: abcdef
  nodename: abcdef
  username: rundeck
  tags: 'rundeck'
```

Comment: OK. So what's your question?

Comment: In your example expected output, why is the first line `hostname1` but the next two lines `hostname2`?

Comment: Your question is essentially this: [How to read a large file - line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line) Once you have read each line, you already know what to do with your f-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open files and work with their lines directly as the file-like is iterable

```py
with open("myfile") as fh:
    for line in fh:  # iterate by-line
        # work with line here
```

If you have a known structure like you presented, you can key creating blocks from features of it such as

- count of lines that form a block (maybe each has exactly 4?)
- is each block separated by an empty line?
- some structure to the blocks (such as the string "host" being present?)

Most yaml logic (such as pyyaml https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation ) allows writing Python dict-likes to a file, all you have to do is create an intermediate dictionary for it to write, and it should be written the structure you're looking for

Perhaps a form like this would work for you

```py
data = {}  # start a new dictionary

with open("myfile") as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):  # iterate by-line
        if index % 4 == 0:
            host = line  # do any needed validation here
            data[host] = {}  # start another dict to write to
        elif index % 4 == 1:
            data[host]["hostname"] = line  # host is still the block header!
        ...  # continue with other fields

# write your dict
with open("destination.yml", "w") as fh:
    yaml.dump(data, fh)
```

This can be adapted to work with whatever separator you like if you don't have exactly 4 fields (ie. incrementing a counter instead of using the lineno's modulus) .. for example if you have variable-length collection of tags which changes the size of the blocks.