# Converting a text document into a jsonl (json lines) format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, text, jsonlines

I want to convert a text file into a json lines format using Python. I need this to be applicable to a text file of any length (in characters or words).

As an example, I want to convert the following text;

```
A lot of effort in classification tasks is placed on feature engineering and parameter optimization, and rightfully so. 

These steps are essential for building models with robust performance. However, all these efforts can be wasted if you choose to assess these models with the wrong evaluation metrics.
```

To this:

```
{"text": "A lot of effort in classification tasks is placed on feature engineering and parameter optimization, and rightfully so."}
{"text": "These steps are essential for building models with robust performance. However, all these efforts can be wasted if you choose to assess these models with the wrong evaluation metrics."}
```

I tried this:

```
text = ""
with open(text.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        text = {"text": line}
```

But not luck.

Comment: So you mean you want to iterate over your text lines, put each in a dictionary using `"text"` as the key, convert it to JSON and append it to a file?

Comment: Something like this could work. I'll need to save it as a .jsonl though

Comment: Then use a filename ending in `.jsonl` when opening a file for writing.

Comment: So at which of these steps was there a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to iterate over the text lines as you've mentioned.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line

Comment: I gave it try but can't get it to work. I tried with open(file.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        jline = {"text": lines}
        text = f.readlines()

Comment: @mkrieger1 Having no luck so far. I tried with open(file.txt, encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        jline = {"text": line}
        text = text.append(jline)

Comment: The code as shown has a rather obvious syntax error. Is that your actual problem? Which parts do you know how to do, and which are you struggling with?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm struggling to convert each line in the text file to a dictionary with "text" as the key and the line of text as the value. I think I am iterating over the file with the for statement but don't know how to convert to the format I need within the loop.

Comment: Did anyone encounter an existing toolchain that does this ? I presume LLM training data generation runs into this question and there should be a functional library for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea of your `for` loop was correct but the line `text = {"text": line}` is just overwriting the previous line every time, whereas what you want is to generate a list of lines.

Try the following:

```
import json

# Generate a list of dictionaries
lines = []
with open("text.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        if line:
            lines.append({"text": line})

# Convert to a list of JSON strings
json_lines = [json.dumps(l) for l in lines]

# Join lines and save to .jsonl file
json_data = '\n'.join(json_lines)
with open('my_file.jsonl', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_data)
```

`splitlines` removes the `\n` characters and `if line:` ignores blank lines.

Comment: This works really well thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way of doing this is to paste the text file into a csv. Make sure to write text in the first cell of the csv then use this code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv(knowledge)
    df.to_json(knowledge_jsonl,
               orient="records",
               lines=True)
```

Not ideal but it works.