# How to edit 1 line in a large text file where memory is an issue

Tags: python

So I have a very large file with a few thousand line that look something like this:

```
this a line
some line are long like this one
some are very longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg like this
some are even longer than that
some are small like the line after this one
a
and this continue on for a few more thousand line
```

So for example I want to edit line 4724 just a random line from it current value: `this is a line that im using as an example` to `I want to edit the line into this`. How can I do that in python. If you need more info just ask me in the comment.

Edit: the file is something around 300KB and yes I have try `readlines()` and it only return 1/3 of the whole file. So that why i say memory is a problem

Comment: how large is the file? If it's anything reasonable (such that you can load it into memory) you could just naively read the whole file, split on lines, update line 4724, and write it back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a large file - line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line)

Comment: @AdamSmith it about 100KB or more that why i can't so readlines

Comment: @MaxNguyen 100KB is nothing on any hardware made in the past (human) generation or so. Just read it.

Comment: Have you *tried* `readlines()`? 100k is nothing.

Comment: It 222kb in this case that I'm talking about with 4671 lines and do `readlines()` return only 1/3 of the file

Comment: @MaxNguyen readlines will never return only part of a large file. Something else is wrong if that's your result. Maybe you have mixed line-endings in the file that appear to be correct in whatever editor you're using to view the file, but means that what you think a "line" is does not match the actual reality of what a line is?

Comment: @MaxNguyen if your file was too big, it would crash and throw a stacktrace ending in `MemoryError`.

Comment: Because the file is too big, so `realines()` encounter a memory issue and only return part of it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the accepted answer on that question is from 2008 and that's Python2 code.

Comment: @AdamSmith then write a new answer or update the existing ones. It's still the same question. (The accepted answer has been maintained until 2020 btw)

Comment: So the answer with the most vote actually solve my problem thanks @mkrieger1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the size of the file, given as 100KB in the comments, you should just naively read the file and change the line in question.

```py
LINE_TO_CHANGE=4724

with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines[LINE_TO_CHANGE - 1] = 'edited line\n'

with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```